# C++ : Accessing the contents of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, grid

I have the following function,

```
void swappingPieceState(std::vector<std::vector<Piece*> >* piecegrid) {

...

}
```

And I wish to access the Piece* stored inside that grid. Traditionally I'd do `piecegrid[0][2]` or something to that effect but since I'm using a pointer to it how do I access it? Sadly it isn't as simple as making a `->` :x 
Help. Thanks.

Comment: Stop using pointers, simply pass by reference instead (change that `*` to `&`).

Comment: This ended up being a better solution to my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to dereference the pointers.

`std::vector<..>* blah` - dereference like `(*blah)[0]` to access element `[0]`.

`std::vector<std::vector<..*>*> blah` - dereference like `(*((*blah)[0]))[0]` to access element `[0][0]`.